# upload a file to my web directory

Tags: php, symfony, urlencode

I'm trying to upload a file (png) to my web directory using an URL:

```
$url = "http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=hello_word&size=100x100";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$fileName = "filename";
$dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/img';
$file->move( $dir , $fileName);
```

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=hello_word&size=100x100): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileName = "filename";
$dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . 
'/../web/uploads/img'.$fileName;
$ch = curl_init('http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?
data=hello_word&size=100x100');
$fp = fopen($dir, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Try something like that. If that doesn't work i'd consider using. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: is it some how convertion my file because im supposed to have a png file

Answer (score 0):

1. Function `file_get_contents` will return a string.
2. You need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php function to encode your URL before passing it to `file_get_contents`.
3. Check `file_put_contents` function in php.net docs.